# How to compare users and users in an OU then add the users using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity " Colorado Students" | Get-ADUser -properties SamAccountName 
$OU = Get-ADUser -SearchBase ‘OU=Colorado,OU=Middle,OU=Student,OU=Colorado-Users,DC=Colorado,DC=9,DC=CO,DC=US’ -Filter *  -Properties SamAccountName

$OU = $OU | Where SamAccountName -notlike $Users 

Foreach ($user in $OU) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity ‘Colorado Students' -Members $_
}
```

I am using Powershell 5.0 I am struggling with finishing this one. I want to compare my users to all users in OU then if users are in OU then add.

Comment: Basically you're looking to add all users on the `OU=Colorado` that _are not_ members of the Group `'Colorado Students'`. Is that so?

Comment: The wording is a little confusing, can you rephrase it? You want to see if the members of *"Colorado Students"* are in that OU, and if they're not, add them to that OU? Wouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Very much sorry, after compare I want to add users in group if in the OU

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is to **Add** all users on the **Colorado OU** that **are currently not** members of the **Colorado Students** group. If that's the case, below code should work:

```
$groupName = 'Colorado Students'
$adGroup = Get-ADGroup $groupName
$OU = 'OU=someOU,OU=Of,OU=Some,DC=Domain,DC=xyz'

# Look for all users on the OU 'someOU' that are NOT
# MemberOf 'Colorado Students'
$hash = @{
    SearchBase = $OU
    LDAPFilter = "(!memberOf={0})" -f $adGroup.DistinguishedName
}
$users = Get-ADUser @hash
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $adGroup -Members $users
```